# Save string to use multiple times in code to avoid fetching the same information multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I am working on a code where I fetch information from an online database through the api they provide. The information I receive is a large block of data arranged in square- and curly brackets. As of now, I fetch the whole block of data every time I want a specific parameter. It becomes a problem as I am limited in how much I can send queries through their api. I would therefore like to fetch the large block of data one time and save it as a variable in the code that I then reference to when I want specific parts of it. I will then be able to get all the specific parts of the data with only one request.

As of now the code I have looks like this:

```
from monkeylearn import MonkeyLearn

ml = MonkeyLearn('my personal API-key')
model_id = 'the id of the model'

text1 = 'This is the text that is analyzed by monkeylearn'
data = ['first text', {'text': text1, 'external_id': 'ANY_ID'}, '']

response = ml.extractors.extract(model_id, data).body

company_name_tag = response[1]['extractions'][0]['tag_name']
company_name = response[1]['extractions'][0]['extracted_text']
```

`response` contains all the information I get from the request so I would like to only have to fetch it once. As of now, if I were to `print(company_name_tag)` and `print(company_name)` it would fetch the data through the api two times. This leads to me reaching my limit on the api a lot faster than necessary.

I appreciate all help with this issue!

Comment: Could you provide us with a bit more of code, especially when you send the query and get the response? Thanks

Comment: I've added more code now. Thank you.

Comment: Simple Create Function To Fetch Data From Api And Store that Fetched object into pickle and use that pickle next time for your operation

Comment: API documentation of `MonkeyLearn` doesn't say anything about calling API again while reading the response. But the input `data` you gave has 2 text values and it will make 2 API calls as per documentation.

Comment: You could use the [`functools.lru_cache()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) function decorator to memoize (cache) results returned from calls to the API.